# How can I fix this error when I try to find a palindrome?

Tags: python, typeerror, palindrome

I need to find if some strings in a set are palindromes, irrespective of their case.
I am reversing the words in the set, converting them to lowercase, then saying if they match, add it to the palindrom set. When i do it, this is what i get.

```
TypeError
Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-621af373c5f5> in <module>()
      5  print(word, palindrome)
      6  wordLower = word.lower
----> 7  if (wordLower==wordLower[::-1]):
      8    palindrome.add(word)

TypeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object is not subscriptable
```

My code is below.

```
words = {'maDam', 'kIng', 'ANna', 'kayak', 'levels', 'dad', 'morning'}
palindrome = set()

for word in words:
 print(word, palindrome)
 wordLower = word.lower
 if (wordLower==wordLower[::-1]):
   palindrome.add(word)
```

Comment: `str.lower` is a function; you need to call it: `word.lower()`

Comment: Line `6` should be `wordLower = word.lower()` you are missing the `()` so you are assigning the method itself, not the result of calling it

Comment: Thank you. I didn't realize that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`word.lower` is the function itself; `word.lower()` is the result of calling that function (which it seems what you actually want).

Comment: Thank you so much!